# Replace, convert, change, a bool False and True to 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried just about every combination on the web, and even though I do not get an error, the bool false does not change to 0

```
df['loan_status_is_great'].replace({'False': 0})
df['loan_status_is_great'].replace('False',0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `df['loan_status_is_great']`?

Comment: Are the values of true and false the booleans `True` and `False` or the strings `'True'` and `'False'` (with a quote around them)?

Comment: Try something like `pd.Series(['False', False]).replace(['False', False], 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is fine enough, But will convert True to 1 and  any other value would be converted to 0

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(['True', 'False','Nan'], dtype='object')
ser = (ser == 'True').astype('int')

print(ser)
```

Output :

```
0    1
1    0
2    0
```